# Custom taxonomy archive empty

Tags: custom-taxonomy, archives

I have created a custom post type with the following arguments:

```
    $args = [
        'label'               => 'Projects',
        'labels'              => $labels,
        'description'         => 'Example projects undertaken',
        'public'              => true,
        'hierarchical'        => false,
        'exclude_from_search' => false,
        'publicly_queryable'  => true,
        'show_ui'             => true,
        'show_in_nav_menus'   => true,
        'show_in_admin_bar'   => true,
        'show_in_rest'        => true,
        'query_var'           => true,
        'can_export'          => true,
        'delete_with_user'    => true,
        'has_archive'         => true,
        'rest_base'           => '',
        'show_in_menu'        => true,
        'menu_position'       => '',
        'menu_icon'           => 'dashicons-clipboard',
        'capability_type'     => 'post',
        'supports'            => ['title', 'editor', 'thumbnail', 'excerpt', 'custom-fields', 'page-attributes'],
        'taxonomies'          => ['category', 'post_tag'],
        'rewrite'             => [
            'with_front' => false,
        ],
    ];
```

I have created a custom taxonomy with the following arguments:

```
    $args = [
        'label'              => 'Services',
        'labels'             => $labels,
        'description'        => 'Services provided',
        'public'             => true,
        'publicly_queryable' => true,
        'hierarchical'       => true,
        'show_ui'            => true,
        'show_in_menu'       => true,
        'show_in_nav_menus'  => true,
        'show_in_rest'       => true,
        'show_tagcloud'      => true,
        'show_in_quick_edit' => true,
        'show_admin_column'  => true,
        'query_var'          => true,
        'sort'               => false,
        'meta_box_cb'        => 'post_categories_meta_box',
        'rest_base'          => '',
        'rewrite'            => [
            'with_front'   => true,
            'hierarchical' => false,
        ],
    ];
```

Individual pages show the taxonomies that they have, but when I follow the taxonomy archive page, it's empty.

Comment: Did you flush your permalinks?

Comment: Yeah, I tried that.

Answer (score 0):

I am clearly an idiot. I was using `get_template_part( 'entry' )` and I had renamed the entry.php file…